# Java, Netbeans: How come the GUI looks different?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, look-and-feel

I'm a Java/Netbeans newbie learning how to make a GUI.

I was following this [tutorial](http://www.javaguicodexample.com/javadesktopguinetbeans4.html), and I noticed that the "finished" product (first picture in that link) doesn't look like the GUI built through the steps.

Why is that? I mean, when I click on the preview button, the GUI looks native (nice) as well. It's just when it's deployed that it looks all...mmm...bad. lol.

Is there a way to make the finished GUI looks native? Is it Netbeans settings or Java settings?

Note: I'm developing this on Windows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the following code to force swing to select the "system" look and feel:

```
String laf = UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName();
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
```

Comment: @HaikalNashuha anywhere before instantiating any Swing components

Answer (score 2):

The default "Look and Feel" is metal-like, which is good and nice for cross-platform applications.

JDK has 4 built-in "look and feel" ('til now), which are:

- com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel
- javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel
- com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel
- com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel

you can try any of these "look and feel"s in 1 line, example code:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel");
```

NOTE: invoke/call this method of changing the "look and feel" before any GUI implementation, or it may throw some exception

Answer (score 1):

This is referred to as the "*look and feel*". You can use various look and feel either when launching your app or programaticaly. See this [Sun tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) for more info.